# rsync - copy a list of files into a remote directory

Tags: backup, rsync, find

I have a rsync command which scans to find freshly created files and then syncs it with the remote PC. Both PC's have had the same file structure until recently.

```
find /mnt/movies -type f -ctime -1 -print0 | rsync -0Prvuz --log-file=/home/daisy/rsync/movies.log -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" --files-from=- --from0 / daisy@melbourne.11111.net:/
```

In this case newly created movies from `/mnt/movies/` are sent to the destination in the same location (`/mnt/movies/`).

Now I need to send them to `/mnt/drive/movies/` which is a change, but for the life of me I cannot work out how to do this.

I understand the `/` after `--files-from=- --from0` causes rsync to place the output of find into the `/` directory of the destination, changing the `/` to `/mnt/drive/` causes rsync to create the directory `/mnt/movies/...` inside the `/mnt/drive` folder. What I would like to see is `/mnt/drive/movies/movie1/1.mkv`

Hope someone can help me with this :/

Comment: You don't need to have the `-0` in your first string of `rsync` options and the `-from0` later on, only one of them, they are the same option.

Answer (score 1):

I've only partially tested my solution, as I don't have a remote system, but I understand that your problem is syncing from `/` to `/` (the entire tree). `rsync` will accept a source and destination, but `find` is giving you full paths, so it can only work if you sync the whole tree. My first thought was to use `sed` to take off the leading part of the paths and then specify the source to `rsync` so it can find those files, and specify the destination also

```
find ... | sed -z 's/^\/mnt\/movies\///' | rsync ...
```

(using `-z` to tell `sed` to use NULL separators from `-print0` and for `--from0`)

But, **steeldriver** helpfully pointed out in a comment that we can achieve the same thing without `sed` using `printf '%P\0'` instead of just `print0` in the `find` command, and this does exactly the same as my idea but much more elegantly (discarding the part of the path specified in the command).

Doing this, each file path will be just `movie1/1.mkv`. So, at the end, instead of `--from0 / daisy@melbourne.11111.net:/` tell `rsync` where to look for that path, and where to find the destination on the remote system:

```
--from0 /mnt/movies daisy@melbourne.11111.net:/mnt/drive/movies
```

This works fine for me with local copying.

suggested complete command:

```
find /mnt/movies -type f -ctime -1 -printf '%P\0' | rsync -Prvuz --log-file=/home/daisy/rsync/movies.log -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" --files-from=- --from0 /mnt/movies daisy@melbourne.11111.net:/mnt/drive/movies
```

Comment: Very smart. There was a `sed` based answer here before, but it ended up looking for files with the `/drive/` element of the path in them.

Comment: I saw it, and the issue with it... I've been puzzling over this for a while on and off! Thanks @Arronical , I hope it works well for OP

Comment: I gave it a test, but only locally, and it seemed to work well. I actually think rsync could handle this without the need for any find command, but need to check the method.

Comment: @Arronical I was going to say the same, my first thought when I saw the question was why do you need `find`? But they have their reasons I guess, I suppose they have old files they don't want to sync and without knowing exactly I would end up giving too many options. But some `rsync` guru will surely know...

Comment: If you want to use this way, then just use `--no-relative` and call it a day!!

Comment: @heemayl `rsync` guru detected :) I thought of it, but couldn't seem to figure it out... need more practice evidently.

Comment: @heemayl but then you wouldn't get the `/movie1/` part of the path for each movie would you?

Comment: Couldn't you just replace `-print0` by `-printf '%P\0'` in the `find` command, instead of using `sed`?

Comment: @steeldriver Indeed, exactly the same result. Although, I can't find anything about this magic `%P`anywhere I tried reading about it. Thanks very much for teaching :)

Comment: @Zanna it may be a GNU extension (I'm not sure) - you should find it documented under the `printf` section of the man page (`%P     File's name with the name of the starting-point under which it was found removed.`).

Comment: @steeldriver I didn't find it in `man bash` (or `man printf`).  It's in `info printf` but under date, something about formatting time as AM/PM! I found it at last at explainshell but described really unclearly & not saying whether it's GNU-only. But TIL, very useful!

Comment: @Zanna sorry I meant the `-printf` section of `man find` (AFAIK `%P` is specific to the `find` command - although `find` borrows the basic format specifier syntax from the C `printf` function, as does the shell's `printf`)

Comment: @steeldriver oh my bad, it is obvious! :)